# I Can't Get Whiteboard To Draw After Setting IT At Toplevel - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

When set as root the whiteboard functions correctly, now moved to a Toplevel popup, lines can only emanate from 0,0 outward, creating nice graphical lines from the top left corner. NOT THE INTENDED OBJECTIVE..mmm.

I suspect it has something to do with my 'global' statements but I'm stuck never the less.  Here is the code as it sits Toplevel within a shell canvas:

```
# WHITEBOARD POPUP
def whiteboardPanel():
    whitePanel = Toplevel(root)
    whitePanel.transient(root)
    whitePanel.title("WHITEBOARD")
    whitePanel.minsize(550,600)
    whitePanel.maxsize(550,600)
    #whitePanel.focus_set()
    #whitePanel.grab_set()
    whitePanel.geometry("550x600+1800+215")

    lastX, lastY = 0, 0

    colour = "black"

    erase = "white"
    thick = 5

    # =========  FUNCTION DEF ==========

    def set_colour_red(event):
       global colour
        colour = "red"
       thick = 5

    def set_colour_green(event):
       global colour
       colour = "green"
       thick = 5

   def set_colour_black(event):
       global colour
       colour = "black"
       thick = 5

   def set_colour_erase(event):
       global colour
       colour = "white"
       thick = 10

   def store_position(event):
       lastX = event.x
       lastY = event.y

   def on_click(event):
       store_position(event)

   def on_drag(event):
       lastX, lastY = 0, 0

       canvas.create_line(lastX, lastY, event.x, event.y, fill=colour, width=thick)
       store_position(event)

canvas = Canvas(whitePanel, width=550, height=600, bg="white")
canvas.pack()
# fill='both', expand=True, padx=6, pady=6)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_drag)
red_id = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30, fill="red")
green_id = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 35, 30, 55, fill="green")
black_id = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 60, 30, 80, fill="black")
erase_id = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 85, 30, 105, fill="white")

canvas.tag_bind(red_id, "<Button-1>", set_colour_red)
canvas.tag_bind(green_id, "<Button-1>", set_colour_green)
canvas.tag_bind(black_id, "<Button-1>", set_colour_black)
canvas.tag_bind(erase_id, "<Button-1>", set_colour_erase)


....somewhere down below
....root.mainloop()
```

Note that other Toplevel windows work fine and there is no issue outside of the drawing issue.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and clarify your question.

Comment: You should not have nested functions (`def` inside another `def`). I suspect if you move the set_colour_red etc functions out of the whiteboardPanel function it would work. Learn about classes if you want to keep your functions in a collection.

Comment: I agree with the Classes option but at this point I am too committed to this format.   I will circle back with the intention of improving my coding convention. Thx

Answer (score 0):

By removing #lastX, lastY = 0, 0 as a global parameter I was able to draw, however the on_click(event) Def does not work so I am currently stuck with red and will need to find another method for changing colours.